# Select-Object Data Failure From Succesful Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: json, powershell, psobject, select-object

I have a working call to a rest service using `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://...`. The call's result, in `JSON`, can be piped the data to `Format-Table -Property ...` and data is shown.

But when `Select-Object -Property ...` is used after the invoke with the same parameters, the `PSObject` has the columns but no data for them. If I use a different webservice the call will work.

[image]

What could be causing the `PSObject` to not show any values?

---

Working Example on public rest web services

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 |
Select-Object -Property title
```

Result

```
@{title=delectus aut autem}
```

**New Failure Different API**

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts | Select-Object -Property text
```

[image]

Comment: the most common reason for `Select-Object` to return objects with empty props is using the wrong name for the props in question. so ... check what your ACTUAL props are named & use those. if you want to change those prop names, use a calculated expression.

Comment: I tried a third public API which sends large amounts of data and it fails too...I am wondering if it is an internal JSON parsing issue with larger data. I have seen that with SQL Server data sproc returns that peg at 2033 characters due to a XML converter used.

Comment: your user name is not type-able on my keyboard. [*sigh ...*] ///// there IS NO `text` prop in the returned data. the only property is `all` & that contains an array that contains objects that have a `.text` property.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Oh I hate that on other users when doing the `@` to tag them. Sorry. Let me look at the `All` property. My initial data is subobjects in an array. Interesting.

Comment: not a serious problem. [*grin*] ///// please take a look at my answer. it only covers the cats link, but the idea otta work elsewhere. [*grin*]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've stumbled upon an unholy combination of two PowerShell oddities when converting JSON *arrays*:

- **`Invoke-RestMethod` and `ConvertFrom-Json` send converted-from-JSON arrays *as a whole* through the pipeline, instead of *element by element*, as usual**:

  - **Note**: In **[PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) 7.0**,  **`ConvertFrom-Json`'s behavior was changed** to align with the usual enumeration-of-elements behavior, and a `-NoEnumerate` switch was added as an opt-in to the old behavior. For the discussion that led to this change, see [GitHub issue #3424](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424).
  - However, as of this writing (PowerShell (Core 7.4.1) **`Invoke-RestMethod` still exhibits this unexpected behavior**; [GitHub issue #15280](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15280) aims to change that.
- `Select-Object` does *not* perform [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), so it looks for the specified property (e.g., `text`) *directly on the array*, where it doesn't exist.

**To demonstrate the problem** with a simple example:

```bash
# Windows PowerShell only:
# Because ConvertFrom-Json sends an *array* (of 2 custom objects) through
# the pipeline, Select-Object looks for property .text on the *array* -
# and can't find it.
# The same applies to Invoke-RestMethod (also still in 
# PowerShell (Core) as of v7.2)
PS> ConvertFrom-Json '[{ "text": "a" }, { "text": "b" }]' | Select-Object text

text
----
       # NO VALUES
```

A **simple workaround** is to enclose the `ConvertFrom-Json` / `Invoke-RestMethod` call in `(...)`, which *forces enumeration* of the array, causing `Select-Object` to work as expected.:

```bash
# (...) forces enumeration
PS> (ConvertFrom-Json '[{ "text": "a" }, { "text": "b" }]') | Select-Object text

text
----
a
b
```

Note that a command such as `Select-Object -Property text` (without `-ExpandProperty`) still output *custom objects that have a `.text` property*, not the `.text` property *values*.

**If all you're interested in is property *values***, the solution is simpler, because you can use the above-mentioned member-access enumeration directly on the array:

```bash
# Using .<propName> on an array (collection) implicitly returns the
# property values from the *elements* of that collection (member-access enumeration).
PS> (ConvertFrom-Json '[{ "text": "a" }, { "text": "b" }]').text
a
b
```

Note how the output now has no `text` header, because it is mere *string values*  that are being output, not custom objects.

Comment: For my situation, placing `Invoke-RestMethod` in parenthesis is working. I was wondering if I would have to call `Invoke-WebRequest` to get the raw json and then covert using `ConvertFrom-Json` in parenthesis instead; but fortunately not. Thanks for your help/insights.

Answer (score 3):

your problem in the 2nd example is that there is NO prop named `text`. [*grin*]

the only prop is `all` and that contains an array of objects that DO contain a prop named `text`. so you need something that can get that deeper prop. one way is to use two `Select-Object` calls. something like this ...

```
$Url = 'https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts'
$RawIRM = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url 
$SO_IRM = $RawIRM |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty all |
    Select-Object -Property text
```

the `$SO_IRM` var now has an array of 178 strings about cats. [*grin*]

Comment: I am getting your answer and it makes sense to dereference `all` for the cats. But my initial data does not have such a property over the array of objects. `[{…}, {…}]` so sadly the `ExpandProperty` doesn't work on my data like on the cat's `all` property. I do have the ability to change the webservice to use a named property, but it might break the react developer on the front end. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan - another way  to get that info would be to run it thru a `.ForEach()` or other loop, and refer to it with `$_.PropName`. you could then use the various props to build a `PSCustomObject` that has the props you want.

Comment: Your analysis of the `https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts` call is correct (and helpful), but it is incidental to @ΩmegaMan's problem; the problem is our old friend,  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424

Comment: @mklement0 - aha! [*grin*] that makes sense ... and is rather freaky. thank you for the info!

Comment: Moving the answer to mklement; sorry. But you helped me over the initial hump and to that end...thanks!

Comment: @ΩmegaMan - that is _good_ news ... his is the real one! [*grin*]  ... and you are quite welcome!